# A math equation with finite terms that plots every real (x,y) point

Tags: calculus, number-theory, graphing-functions

Is it possible to create an equation that plots every point?

You can stack plotted equations by moving everything to one side such that it equals 0 and multiplying by another equation that is in the same set-up.

E.g. 
$$(y-(x^2))\cdot(y-(x^2)-1)\cdot(y-(x^2)-2)\cdot(y-(x^2)-3)=0$$

This stacks 4 quadratic equations. You could stack infinite equations of the form `y-x^2+c=0` where c adjusts by infinitesimals from -∞ to ∞, however this equation would have **infinite terms**.

Is there an equation in *finite terms* that will plot every real (X,Y) value?

Comment: how does an equation 'plot' terms?

Comment: @LinAlg Forgive me if I'm not using the correct terminology, I'm not the most versed in math. I do hope that the correct words, whatever they may be, can be inferred though by the explanation in my question. I didn't want to say function because of failing the vertical-line test, so I'm not sure what word to use.

Comment: Are you asking: "Is there a finitely long equation in $x$ and $y$ whose soutions are every possible combination of real $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @timtfj Yes, if you were to plot the finitely long equation on a cartesian plane the whole thing would be solidly filled in.

Comment: I mean an equation like $x+y=x+y$ would do it

Comment: $0=0$ is satisfied for all $x,y$

Comment: There are space-filling curves, but I don't know enough about those to know whether they quite do the job as you've defined it.

Comment: @timtfj `x+y=x+y` hahaha it seems so obvious now. I get too caught up in the function-manipulation I forget to step back and think about the bigger picture of what plotting even is. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @timtfj Yes space filling curves are definitely more in line of what I was looking for, however the x+y equation definitely satisfies the question as well so no need to get more complex.

Comment: @timtfj I think the issue is going to be what kind of function the OP is looking for, and whether the construction of a space filling curve can be said to have "finite terms". If we are to understand the question to be asking for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which has a $0$ at every point in the plane, the only possible function is $f\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could try $$x+y=x+y$$ I suppose.

**Edit:** I'd like to comment on the infinitely-many-quadratics idea in the question. It's quite appealing: the solutions to the equation form an infinite family of parabolas, each shifted vertically from the one before, one for each bracketed expression. It's tempting to try to fill the plane by putting them infinitely close together. But there's a problem.

The left hand side of of the equation lists the quadratics—meaning there are countably many of them, and hence countably many corresponding parabolas.

For a given value of $x$, we need a parabola for each possible $y$ value. That is, one for every real number. But the real numbers are uncountable, so we haven't got enough parabolas.

Comment: It seems so obvious, _now_. Haha, thanks!

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I hope that's finite enough for you ;-)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw BTW, there's a problem with the infinite parabolas idea: they're only countably infinite, which means that there can never be enough of them to cover all the $y$ values for a given $x$ (since the real numbers are uncountable).

Answer (score 1):

What about something like $$x=\frac{\{r\}}{1-\{r\}}\cos\bigg(\frac{\{r\}}{1-\{r\}}+2\pi\phi[r]\bigg)$$$$y=\frac{\{r\}}{1-\{r\}}\sin\bigg(\frac{\{r\}}{1-\{r\}}+2\pi\phi[r]\bigg)$$with $r$ from 0 to ∞, & $$\phi={\sqrt{5}±1\over2}$$ (or any other irrational number for that matter), so that you'd be plotting an infinitude of infinite spirals, with phases evenly distributed around 'the clock'.

Actually, I think there might well be shortcomings with this - *countability* -wise. But something kind of *in that vein*, perhaps.

Actually, I've just noticed that someone else has addressed this countability problem!

I am beginning to wonder whether it might perhaps be *fundamentally* impossible ... *unless* there's some way to circumvent the problem with $$\operatorname{range-of-values-in}\{r\}\cdot\cdot\cdot \operatorname{uncountable}$$&$$\operatorname{range-of-values-in}[r]\cdot\cdot\cdot \operatorname{countable} .$$ If no-one furnish me with a convincing argument to the contrary, I'm rolling with the idea that there's some *ultraslick* way of doing it! ... like that construction for a distribution of points on a sphere by which Möser's classical limit on the number of closest neighbours points on a sphere (distributed in a certain way) can have was circumvented ... something of *that* grade of slickity.

Comment: I'm still happy with $x+y=x+y$ (That's about as short as I can get it while still keeping $x$ and $y$ in.)

Comment: @timtfj -- I _you_ 're the culprit who spoiled my (& the other contributor's) _wonderful idea_ with all that fuss about _countability_!! ¶ Using mine as an example though, I think you _would_ need an uncoubtable _number of spirals ... _even though_ the number of points on each spiral is uncountable.

Comment: @timtfj -- And if you're wondering what I mean about busting that limit by _Möser_ (_not_ Moore) ... check out the Paul Erdos collected papers № 1989-02, @ https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/Erdos.html. I have a feeling you'll _love - __love___ it! It's one of those ideas that _truly_ break the mould of thought.

Comment: If its any consolation, I think your spirals would look nicer than either my big block of black or the parabilas!

Comment: Also I'd like to know whether some sort of space-filling curve can do it, or whether everything defined that way is doomed to countability problems.

Comment: I think: a radial line from the origin crosses each spiral countably many times, and there are countably many spirals, hence countable*countable = countable points accounted for. So, more spirals needed. Correct?

Comment: @timtfj -- oh yes - no problemo - I do acknowledge in my answer itself that I'm beginning to discern these countability problems. And _your_ method has two parameters: it's basically (x,y)=(r,s), if I interpret it aright. That's why I cite that paper - _not_  because it addresses _this_ problem - it doesn't - but because ... well it's kindof _related_, being about points on a surface ... but mainly because it evinces that rare _extreme resourcefulness_ that just has you staggered - the way it overthrows a conjecture that is so 'obviously' true: and that species of thought @ this problem ...

Comment: Oh yes, I got that and I'll have a look at the link! It sounds interesting (assuming my maths is up to it)

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you

Comment: @timtfj -- it's one of those, I would say, that doesn't require any particularly advanced particular _item_ of mathematical knowledge, but _does_ require a _stout & steady __concentration___ on the part of the person trying to take it in ... you know the sort of thing ... you'll see what I mean when you look at it!

Comment: @Albert Renshaw -- _if_ what you mean is a function of $x$ & $y$ _in terms of a single parameter_, which is my interpretation of it, you _might well_ be out of luck, I'm afraid! But it's a _dämpfenfd und räuchend __good question___ that's far deeper than it appears on the face of it - and I think it might be one of those of which the solution, whether it be the actual _exhibition_ of such a function, or merely the _existence_ of one, invokes the so-called _axiom of choice_ ... which means ... _seriously_ tricky!

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey I've saved the link, for when it's daytime here. :-) Re the spirals and my radial line: at each intersection it crosses the $r$th spiral for the $s$th time, so to speak, so counting the intersections is just the same as counting rational numbers $\frac rs$ with the famous zigzag thing. That's how I'm imagining it. (I like the irrational spacing of the spirals, BTW.)

Comment: @timtfj -- yes, that _irrational number_ trick is just a standard recipe for getting a spread like that - _any_ irrational number will do, but φ is in a sense optimum: if you have two sequences of pulses & you want them maximally spaced, the optimum frequency ratio is φ; and if you want a cuboid cavity that maximally 'foils' reinforcement of resonances, then the optimum ratio is 1:φ:φ²; etc. This is a consequence of φ being in a sense the _most irrational_ of all irrational numbers: it has the slowest converging sequence-of-rational-approximations of _all_ irrational numbers.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey I'm thinking that should also make $1:\phi$ the most perfectly out-of-tune musical interval, but that's a bit tangential. (I think it'll be a hideously sharp minor 6th. I'll work it out tomorrow.)

Comment: @timtfj -- Yes - certainly - it would ... at least _in that sense_ of the harmonics of the notes being maximally separated - I wouldn't say its 'tangential' _atall_, really. & an infinitude of similar examples. φ is quite _respectable_ as one of the fundamental mathematical constants: it doesn't have the distinguishing feature of a _thoroughly unique_ fundamental definition, as things like e, π & γ (& others, like the Gauss-Kuz'min-Wirsing constant - a curiferous one I only discovered recently) have; but it does crop-up here & there in really quite _respectable_ formulæ.

Comment: Fun note: Once filling in every point, if you set all terms to zero then divide your function by a second function which is also modified to fit the form `f(y,x)=0`, you will achieve a true inverse function, in which every point is plotted except the values of your original `f(y,x)` function. [As you'd be dividing by zero on those points]

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey That might actually stop it sounding dissonant—dissonance is most intense when beats of around $10$ or $15$ Hz happen between harmonics of one note and another. (And pianos get away with using equal temperament by striking the string in just the right place to suppress the most problematic harmonic.)

Comment: @Albert Renshaw -- If I'm understanding you aright ... I think indeed finding just _one_ such function would indeed be tantamount to finding an infinitude of them ... through basically an unlimited set of transformations, inversions, etc.

Comment: @timtfj -- _and also_ by reason of musical notes having a _finite length_ - by reason of which in turn they have an intrinsic _uncertainty_ or _spread_ of frequencies - or _tolerance_ in frequency.. ¶ As I said, the _sense in which_ the notes are _deemed_ dissonant is an essential matter - & _technical_ might not necessarily coincide with _æsthetick_.

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey Absolutely. I think this one would sound "out of tune but not discordant", and  hence puzzling to the listener.

Comment: @timtfj -- I think more likely than not there's some composer who's tried it ... what with that kind of 'innovation' being considered _artistic_ these days! I think some of it is just _barmy_ ... but others have some virtue in them ... one of my favourites in that vein is rhythms based on the _Morse-Thue word_.